# Javascript check/uncheck all checkboxes and write values to textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, input, textarea

This is my first js script so be gentle with me :)

The problem is when I click on check all button, all checkboxes are checked but it won't write values to textarea, if I click individual checkboxes then the value is added/removed and that is ok, I'm just stuck on that check all/uncheck all button.

http://jsfiddle.net/LAcgE/74/

```js
function check(chk) {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
    chk[i].checked = true ;
}

function uncheck(chk) {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
    chk[i].checked = false ;
}

var itemsAdded = Array();

function movetext(text) { 
    var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
    if ( i >= 0) { 
        itemsAdded.splice(i,1); 
    }
    else {
        itemsAdded.push(text);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value=itemsAdded.join("\n"); 
}
```

```html
<form action='#' method='post'>

  <input type='checkbox' value='aaa' name="add" onclick='movetext(this.value)'/>a
  <input type='checkbox' value='bbb' name="add" onclick='movetext(this.value)'/>b
  <input type='checkbox' value='ccc' name="add" onclick='movetext(this.value)'/>c
  <input type='checkbox' value='ddd' name="add" onclick='movetext(this.value)'/>d
  <input type='checkbox' value='eee' name="add" onclick='movetext(this.value)'/>e
    
  <input type="button" value="check all" onClick="check(this.form.add)">
  <input type="button" value="uncheck all" onClick="uncheck(this.form.add)">
    
  <textarea id="result" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your check and uncheck functions with this

```
function check(chk) {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
    {
        chk[i].checked = true ;
        movetext(chk[i].value);
    }
}

function uncheck(chk) {
    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
    {
        chk[i].checked = false ;
        movetext(chk[i].value);
    }
}
```

You just have to manually call the other method. I tried it in your fiddle.

Comment: You may want to rewrite your movetext method however. If you check all, then uncheck one of the boxes, they become unsynched. This also happened in your original fiddle.

Comment: it works! but when i check "a" manually, then "uncheck all" button, textarea should be cleared, not populated with b,c,d,e values :) try it yourself :)

Comment: ah you found that too :) can you help with that movetext function or should i create new question?

Comment: I'm a little busy to figure out a rewrite to the movetext method right now. It should probably check to see if the text is there before adding it again or vice versa. Or maybe uncheck all should call a method that clears the box and check all does the opposite.

Comment: thanks for your time, i will create a new question :)

Comment: you're amazing, it works perfectly in all combinations :) and you saved me waiting for 90 minutes to post a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to call movetext() function in check() and uncheck() function.
Add this after you do check/uncheck:

```
movetext(chk[i].value);
```